# How can I add a series with multiindex to a dataframe specifying its index to be the Series' name

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm trying to add a Series with multiindex to a dataframe, and I want to set the index of that new row to be the name of Series

```
stock  factors  dates     
a      0        2019-01-01     0.0
       1        2019-01-01    27.0
       0        2019-01-01     7.0
       1        2019-01-01    24.0
```

What I have tried is the code below:

```
series.name = 'Myindex'
df = df.append(series)
```

The goal is to add a new row to the existing dataframe with index set to be 'Myindex'

But I got

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: How looks dataframe? Can you add 1, 2 rows of data sample?

Comment: It's a new dataframe with no values

Answer (score 1):

I  believe you need create columns in new `DataFrame` by index values and then use `rename`:

```
print (series)
stock  factors  dates     
a      0        2019-01-01     0.0
       1        2019-01-01    27.0
       0        2019-01-01     7.0
       1        2019-01-01    24.0
dtype: float64

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=series.index)

df = df.append(series.rename('Myindex'))
print (df)
stock            a                                 
factors          0          1          0          1
dates   2019-01-01 2019-01-01 2019-01-01 2019-01-01
Myindex        0.0       27.0        7.0       24.0
```

Comment: I found the real problem is that I have several series to be added to this dataframe, but they are with different multiindexes. Maybe I should reset their indexes to the same before the adding

Comment: @Bubblethan - yes, your solution working for me, but was necessary `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=series.index)`

Comment: @Bubblethan - one idea - is possible use `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=series1.index.union(series2.index))` ?